# Respawn with SQl server: -"BeginExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql-server, integration-testing, xunit, .net-4.8

I am trying to use the [respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn) library in my Xunit test project.

My fixture class looks like this:

```
public class DBFixture : IAsyncLifetime
    {
        private readonly Checkpoint checkpointSystem;
        
        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get => @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=user;Pwd=pass";
        }
        
        public DatabaseFixture()
        {
            checkpointSystem = new Checkpoint
            {
                DbAdapter = DbAdapter.SqlServer,
                TablesToInclude = new[] { "MyTable" },
                SchemasToInclude = new[] { "MyDB" }
            };
        }
        
         public async Task ResetAsync()
        {
            
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    await this.checkpointSystem.Reset(conn);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to call from my test class the resetASync method I got this error:

> "BeginExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized

I have also tried as the github page suggest "Respawner.CreateAsync", but I guess that that method is not available with the version 4.0 of respawn (I am using that version, since the more recent ones are not compatible with net framework 4.8, which is the .net used in the test project, for the time being it is not possible to migrate that project to .net core)

I also tried implementing remote async like this:

```
public async Task ResetAsync()
        {
            
            await checkpointSystem.Reset(this.ConnectionString);
        }
```

Same problem though. I guess the documentation I checked does not offer a good example for projects using SQl server and the version 4.0 of respawn. But after looking for examples in Github in classes like these ones I cannot still figure out how to use it.

https://github.com/FredrikAugust/bibliotek/blob/436f4ef795dc565caccd6190d73bc3ea005c5507/Application.IntegrationTests/Common/DbFixture.cs

or
https://github.com/renetguerra/Inventory.DDD.API/blob/18bf28cc77aa1c9113f8790a5dba2cecf360a5e6/Inventory.DDD.Integrations.Tests/TestBase.cs

Comment: Does the table `MyTable` exist in the database? I got this error when I tried to tell Respawner to include a table that I later found out didn't exist.